# How to create table with DOM in order jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following variable:

```
  var cars = [
      {model: "BMW", count: 23, details: "<p>I like <b>X6</b> from Germany</p>"},
      {model: "Hyundai", count: 30, details: "<p>I have <b>Verna</b> from Korea</p>"},
      {model: "Toyota", count: 08, details: "<p>Small <b>Yaris</b> from Japan</p>"},
      {model: "Fiat", count: 12, details: "<p>Latest <b>500c</b> from Italy</p>"}
  ]
```

What I'm trying to do is, create a table with only 3 columns, that display only Model and count like so 'BMW(23)', then when I click on 'BMW' only it opens an HTML page which shows 'details'.

I have looked at [How do I create HTML table using jQuery dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846253/how-do-i-create-html-table-using-jquery-dynamically) but I'm not able to achive the requrienment:

- The list should always be displayed in a three column layout, also in the case of, for instance, only four models in total.
- List should be ordered alphabetically.
- Clicking on each car, model should display additional information about the car (some html) as listed above.
- The number of cars in the list can vary at any moment.

Thanks...

Comment: You're asking quite a bit, sorting the array, creating the HTML, making it open a new page etc. and it doesn't look like you've tried anything yourself. This is not a place where we write your code for you, it's a place where you can get help once you're stuck with an actual problem.

Comment: @adeneo, I have tried in JS only but it's working as it should. Also I found creating table with DOM in JS could confuse you. I want to know if there is more simpler way.I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vRPUT/1/)

```
// sort the cars alphabetically by model
cars.sort(function(a, b) { return a.model > b.model; });

// create table
var table = $("<table></table>");

$.each(cars, function(idx, car) {

  var row = $("<tr></tr>");

  row.append($("<td></td>").html(car.model));
  row.append($("<td></td>").html(car.count));
  row.append($("<td></td>").html(car.details));

  table.append(row);
});

// insert the table somewhere in your dom
$(document.body).append(table);
```

---

**Edit**: I was originally using `.text` to set the content of the `TD` elements. However, because you have HTML in your data object, I used `.html` to set the table cell contents.

Comment: $("<table>") is equivalent to $("<table></table>"), if you wanted to make it shorter

Comment: egydamo pick him as chosen answer with green tick on the left if it solved your question.

Comment: @benjaminbenben, thanks for the tip. I prefer to be explicit wherever possible.