# Dynamic Year Calendar in JSP using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I need to implement a dynamic yearly calendar, there will be a drop-down box which has up to 10 years from now, if a year was selected and the 'Set' button was pressed. A calendar for a whole year will be displayed in the JSP. Like this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2rBi.png)

This calendar will also be construct with check boxes, since I will use the Struts's html:multibox tag. Can someone give me an idea on how to do this in JS or jQuery?

Note: I am only allowed to use JSP, JS and jQuery. No AJAX or other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle everything in javascript (which I recommend), you can start by looking at these items:

1. Capturing the selected year using `.change()` https://api.jquery.com/change/
2. Get the list of days in each months [Find all the days in a month with Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146418/find-all-the-days-in-a-month-with-date-object)
3. Create a dynamic tables to represent each months which contain checkboxes [How do I create HTML table using jQuery dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846253/how-do-i-create-html-table-using-jquery-dynamically)
4. If you ever need to set the checkboxes' value from the server-side, just render them as hidden inputs or javascript variables values then use them to check/uncheck the checkboxes using jquery [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Since we are doing most of the things using javascript, avoid relying on struts taglibs (eg: html:multibox) because they are executed (rendered) before javascript.