# Generating a HTML table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Im using jQuery to generate a table:

```
var container = jQuery(".container");
container.append("<table class='table table-striped'>");
container.append("<tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr>");
container.append("<tr><td>2</td><td>B</td></tr>");
container.append("<tr><td>3</td><td>C</td></tr>");
container.append("</table>");
```

The above code generates the following HTML (tested in Chrome and Safari):

[image]

As you can see: The table is closed before the `tr` are injected.

The expected result is of course a table with three rows.

**Question:** Why is the code not generating the expected table, what am I missing here?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846253/how-do-i-create-html-table-using-jquery-dynamically

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: try with this: http://codepen.io/olaferlandsen/pen/yJmKAK