# jquery ajax creating and appending to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

This is my CSV file:

```
Item, Quantity, Price;
LED, 100, $10;
PIR, 1, $5;
DS18B20, 10, $5;
```

This is my jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.csv",
        success: function(result) {
            var data = result;
            var arr = data.split(";");
            var len = arr.length - 1;
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            while (a < len) {
                var orr = arr[a].split(",");
                var err = orr.length;
                b = 0;
                while (b < err) {
                    if (a == 0) {
                        alert(orr[b]);
                        b = b + 1;
                    } else if (a > 0) {
                        alert(orr[b]);
                        b = b + 1;
                    }
                };
                a = a + 1;
            };
        }
    });
});
```

this code gets the data and alerts. How do I get all the data turn the into a ordered table (i.e. the first line should be a table header).

Comment: Here you go: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp. And if you want to step things up, you might want to look at: React (https://github.com/reactjs) or knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks...And also what should i learn to use react.js ?

Comment: The React framework is a lightweight javascript library that enables binding data from javascript to HTML elements. The only thing you need to learn to use react is Javascript and HTML.

Comment: But i want to do it with only Jquery... How do i do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413952/how-to-create-a-new-table-with-rows-using-jquery-and-wrap-it-inside-div
Not quite an exact duplicate, but it covers creating a table and adding rows to it.

Comment: But how do i use this code in my project? It's not very straightforward.