# Dynamically Inject new HTML into a web page and be able to access any new DOM elements that are in the "new" injected HTML

Tags: html, jquery

I found this link that suggested injecting a table into a div.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413952/how-to-create-a-new-table-with-rows-using-jquery-and-wrap-it-inside-div)

Here is an example of new HTML that I want to inject:

```
<br />
<br />


<LSz class='LineSpaceDouble'>
Hi, <p class='FIRST_NAME'> </p> <br><br>
Hi <p class='FIRST_NAME'> </p>, my name is <p class='MYNAME'> </p> .
More Text.<br>
</LSz>

<br />


     <label for='PBirthDate'>Primary Birthdate:</label>
     <input id='PBirthDate' class='input100' type='text' name='PBirthDate' placeholder='mm/dd/yr' size='10'>
     <span class='focus-input100'></span>
<br />
```

Here is my current jq code that does the injection:

```
var S = J;

$(S).appendTo('#Script_Displayed');
```

J holds HTML text to be injected.

and Script_Displayed is the id of the div

THAT works -- in that the "text" is indeed injected into the web page where the div is located.

My problem is when I attempt to change a value:

```
var Z = document.getElementsByClassName('FIRST_NAME');

Z.innerHTML  = "Anthony";
```

The new innerHTML  value does not appear on the web page.

What Can I do to make these changes visible?

Comment: Does the injected HTML include new JavaScript code?  It's certainly very strange that `$` is defined and then somehow is re-defined to something else.

Comment: I concluded that the newly injected text which was JQ in syntax was not acceptable.  As such, I changed to js code as I have edited the question above.  I'm not getting an error -- but my new value changes are not being displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not a single element.  So this won't work by default:

```
Z.innerHTML  = "Anthony";
```

Instead, loop over the collection to assign the `innerHTML` value to each element in the collection:

```js
var Z = document.getElementsByClassName('FIRST_NAME');
for (let el of Z) {
  el.innerHTML  = "Anthony";
}
```

```html
Hi, <p class='FIRST_NAME'> </p> <br><br>
Hi <p class='FIRST_NAME'> </p>, my name is <p class='MYNAME'> </p> .
More Text.<br>
```